# Find a file based on specifications

Tags: files, filesystem, directory, find

Maybe this is a duplicate but how do I find a file (that I don't know the name of) based on some specifications?

For example how do I find a file that:

- Is human-readable
- Has exactly 1033 bytes in size
- Is not executable

In a certain directory with tons of files, some executable and some non human-readable?

Comment: If you run `man find` on your system, it will show you all the commands you can use to find exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by human-readable? Not binary?

Comment: You may also need to consider by whom the file should be "not executable"

Comment: @terdon I suppose it's readable in the sense of non-machine code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Terrance's comment, I found the answer.

You can simply do `find -readable -size 1033c`, that finds a readable file with the size of 1033 bytes.

Comment: "readable" and "human-readable" are not generally considered to be the same thing

Comment: In this case I suppose it's readable in the sense of non-machine code

Comment: @Pero then this doesn't do what you want. The readable flag will find files that your user has read access to, not files that you as a human can necessarily read. It is about permissions.

Comment: Well, found it anyways, I had read permissions and it was the only file with 1033 bytes in size, so...

Answer (score 0):

You execute the following command
`find . -type f -size 1033c ! -executable`

this command find a non-executable file and its size 1033 bytes in the working directory